Xamarin Android App Crash on Android 15: mono-context.c:474, condition 'fpctx->head.magic == FPSIMD_MAGIC' not met
I am encountering a crash in my Xamarin Android application, but it occurs only on Android 15. The app crashes with the following error:
* Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mono/utils/mono-context.c:474, condition `fpctx->head.magic == FPSIMD_MAGIC' not met
2024-11-13 16:54:47.140  4870-4925  libc                    com.leadrat.black.mobile.droid       A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 4925 (Finalizer), pid 4870 (ck.mobile.droid)
2024-11-13 16:54:48.269  4929-4929  DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Cmdline: com.leadrat.black.mobile.droid
2024-11-13 16:54:48.269  4929-4929  DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  pid: 4870, tid: 4925, name: Finalizer  >>> com.leadrat.black.mobile.droid <<<
2024-11-13 16:54:48.288  4929-4929  DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A        #01 pc 000000000028f7bc  /data/app/~~4UFGvtgS82JG2q09-eSKFg==/com.leadrat.black.mobile.droid--whkq7HH4uYUPnsFZLX53w==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (offset 0xbef000) (monoeg_assert_abort+24)


Context:
Platform: Xamarin.Forms targeting Android
Device: Crashes only on Android 15 (other versions work fine)
Mono Runtime Version: Embedded runtime is used
Error Trigger: Happens inconsistently, often during finalizer thread execution or background tasks.
Steps Taken:
Updated the full SDK to the latest version.
Adjusted the target version based on project requirements.
Verified all managed objects are properly disposed.
Checked for memory leaks and ensured memory usage is under limits.
Reviewed custom P/Invoke calls for compatibility issues.
Verified all dependencies are updated to their latest versions.
Questions:
What does the FPSIMD_MAGIC assertion failure signify on Android 15?
Could this be related to changes in Android 15's runtime or Mono compatibility?
Are there any specific debugging steps to isolate this issue on Android 15?
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

You will probably get a quicker resolution if you report it to the .NET Android team. See https://github.com/dotnet/android, then Issues and file the issue.
